# Из текстового файла вывести строку под номером N, не используя функций для обработки бинарных файлов

Tags: c, строки, файлы, ввод

Нужно чтобы выводилась строка под номером N из текстового файла (блокнот) также нельзя использовать функции для работы с бинарными файлами (fread, fwrite , SEEK и прочие) желательно чтобы были только Си функции

Comment: Они б тебе всё равно не помогли. Открываешь файл и читаешь построчно.

Comment: Qwertiy , ну я просто сделал данный код но я там использовал функции fread а вот как обойтись без нее не знаю вот мой код :    int n;
 char a,ch;
 int j = 1;
 fopen_s(&f, "numbers.txt", "rb");
 do {
  printf("n=");
  a = scanf("%d", &n);
  if (!a || (n <= 0)) printf("Ошибка ввода");

 } while (!a || (n <= 0));

 for (int i = 0; fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, f); i++) {
  if ((j >= n) && (j <= n)) {
   
           _putch(ch);
  }
  if (ch == '\n') j++;
 }
 fclose(f);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так

```
FILE * f = fopen(filename,"rt");
char buf[1024];
int i = 0;
for(; i < N; ++i)
{
    if (fgets(buf,1024,f) == NULL) 
    {
        puts("No Nth line in the file");
        break;
    }
}
if (i == N) printf("Nth line: %s\n",buf);
```

Можно добавить обработку ну очень длинных строк - если при чтении `buf` не заканчивается на `\n` - читать еще без увеличения `i`.

Можно воспользоваться (не совсем стандартной, насколько мне известно) [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline).

Comment: Добавьте в ответ и необходимые заголовочные файлы, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Leonid А еще функцию `main`? Ну что за детский сад, честное слово - не просто поставить тарелку, но еще и из ложечки покормить?...

Comment: Ну если приходится расписывать самые базовые вещи, то может и стоит. Вы же не 3D анимацию здесь представили.